# JSON from Servlet to Ajax to HTML - no error message

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I am just finishing up this project. I have a JSON string

```
{"data":{"id":"YPekRdk","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1429674575,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":600,"height":200,"size":85694,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":0,"deletehash":"AZi041RwarCFD3I","name":"","link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/YPekRdk.png"},"success":true,"status":200}
```

I send it from my servlet

```
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(imgurImageJson));
```

to my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var array1 = [];

        $('#sortable2 .selectedItemImg').each(function () {
            array1.push($(this).attr('src'));
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'generate',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: array1.join('\n'),

            success: function (data) {
                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (listID, mapData) {
                    $("#displayGeneratedURL").append("<p>" + mapData.id + "</p>");
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

and try to view it on my jsp

```
#displayGeneratedURL{
            color:  white; font-family: Geneva,Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;
        }

<div id="displayGeneratedURL">Result should be here somewhere</div>
```

With this I was getting a browser message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I changed my datatype to application/json and a few other things and that error message goes away and instead just nothing happens whatsoever (as output to the screen or to that console).

The code I am using is replicated mostly from working code I use with another servlet, however it could still be inappropriate/wrong to use with that Gson call with that json string, but I don't know. It could also be that my function in the ajax is completely wrong.

Can you see anything that's wrong?

Update:

I tried changing the servlet response to

```
response.getWriter().write(imgurImageJson);
```

and the datatype to `dataType: 'text/html'`, there is nothing displayed still and no error messages (this gave the > error when datatype was left as text only)

Update: I changed my ajax function to this

```
success: function (data) {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

and it does not make an alert box or do anything

IMAGE OF MY CONSOLE IS HERE

[image]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZivJ.jpg

(additional plain link because otherwise it goes very tiny)

Update:

This is my developer console POST Response

[image]

EDIT: Here is my FULL servlet code (very messy):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mainClasses;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeDebug.getContext;

/**
 *
 * @author J
 */
@WebServlet(name = "ImageGenerationServlet", urlPatterns = { "/generate" })
public class ImageGenerationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request
     *            servlet request
     * @param response
     *            servlet response
     * @throws ServletException
     *             if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException
     *             if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ImageGenerationServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet ImageGenerationServlet at "
                    + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed"
    // desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request
     *            servlet request
     * @param response
     *            servlet response
     * @throws ServletException
     *             if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException
     *             if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request
     *            servlet request
     * @param response
     *            servlet response
     * @throws ServletException
     *             if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException
     *             if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

        // List imageList = Arrays.asList(request.getParameter("button"));
        //
        // System.out.println(imageList);
        //
        // ArrayList <String> imageURLs = new
        // ArrayList(Arrays.asList(imageList));
        //
        // System.out.println(imageURLs);
        // ArrayList <String> imageURLs = new
        // ArrayList(request.getParameter("button"));
        // String postResponse = request.getParameter("button");
        // ArrayList<Map> imageMap = new ArrayList<Map>();
        // String[] urls1 = postResponse.split(",");
        // ImageController.controlImage(urls1);
        List<String> imageURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            String line;
            do {
                line = reader.readLine();

                                if (line !=null){
                imageURLs.add(line);
                                }

            } while (line != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        ;

        try {
            // int size = imageURLs.length();

            // Our steps are:
            // 1) Retrieve array of image srcs from our jsp via jquery and parse
            // to string array.
            // 2) Process the array in ImageController to create composite
            // image, upload to local server
            // and return local image url.
            // 3) Transfer the image to imgur by sending our local image url to
            // the imgur API.
            // Retrieve the image's new imgur url in json string.
            // 4) Parse the string so that we have just the url in json format.
            // 5) Send this back to our jsp via jquery and print to screen.
            ImageController imageController = new ImageController();

            String filePath = imageController.controlImage((ArrayList<String>) imageURLs);

                        System.out.println(filePath);

            // String generatedImageFilePath =
            // ImageController.controlImage((ArrayList<String>) imageURLs);
            // UploadController uploadController = new UploadController();
            String imgurImageJson = UploadController.getImgurContent(filePath);



//                 response.setContentType("json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

//                 response.getWriter().write("hello");
                response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(imgurImageJson));

//                response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(imgurImageJson));

//                        System.out.println(imgurImageJson);
//
//          Scanner file = new Scanner("imgurImageJson.json");
//          String imgurImageJsonSample = file.nextLine();
//          file.close();
//
//          JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
//          JsonObject obj = parser.parse(imgurImageJsonSample)
//                  .getAsJsonObject();
//          String imgurl = obj.get("link").toString();
//          System.out.println(imgurl);

            // uploadedImageJson
            // 1) retrieve array of urls
            // 2) send to imagegenerationcontroller
            // 3) send to uploadcontroller
            // 4) retrieve and parse the json response to get the imgur url
            // 5) response from here to user
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageGenerationServlet.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: FYI if your content type is `application/json` then you dont need to parse it else you should parse. Also check the response send by the server using browser developer tool

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited in an image that shows my developer log. I changed my code (as also shown) to ONLY make an alert but that does not fire whatsoever.

Comment: That image shows a 404 response. What's your servlet url ? Given that your success function does not fire at all and seeing the 404 response, are you sure there is no error happening on the Servlet side?

Comment: please show us the request and response from network tab of developer tool, not the console.

Comment: that 404 is due to an image not loading when i perform another POST request on another servlet, you can safely ignore it as far as i can imagine

Comment: Cerlin, that image shows the Network tab .... Ignore everything above the POST that you see there. The POST works as you can see, just the Alert doesnt happen

Comment: please click on that post request (the one with `generate` as url) and share us the response inside it.

Comment: ah, nice one. there are tools hidden all over the place :) i added the picture. it looks like it is ignoring the fact that i'm trying to send it a response from doPOST (it is defaulting to processRequest ? I can edit in the FULL servlet code if you want.

Comment: i think i have found the answer, i was calling `processRequest(request, response);` at the start of my servlet's getPost method. ill keep working and then confirm. THANKYOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP CERLIN BOSS

Answer (score 0):

i found that my servlet's getPost() method was calling my servlet's processResquest() method.

i have a feeling that call was generated there by default and i had forgotten to comment it out/delete it days ago when i first created the servlet.

thanks to Cerlin Boss who showed me how to look at the actual POST response that was being created, by clicking the POST instance in my browser developer console, and to Ramp